# How can I append key value pair to the url which already existed key value pair in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a click functions.In 1st click function i add the key value pair for existing url like this

```
$scope.OnItemClick = function (bedroom) {
    $location.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({bedrooms:bedroom});
}
```

so in remaining functions.I want to add extra key value pair based on existing url

```
$scope.range = function (range) {
    $location.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({budget:range});
}

$scope.status = function (status) {
    $location.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({status:status});
}
```

i tried to adding key value pair  but its over riding each other like this.

```
1st click : ../#/builders/1?bedrooms=1
2nd click :../#/builders/1?budget:5(overriding)
3rd click :../#/builders/1?status:9(overriding)
```

so i want to do like this based on clicking functions:

```
../#/builders/1?budget=5&bedrooms=1&status=9
../#/builders/1?bedrooms=1&status=9&budget=5
../#/builders/1?bedrooms=1&budget=5&status=9
```

Comment: it seems like you want to use the current path, rather than `"/builders/"+r.id` each time.

Comment: this url "/builders/"+r.id is ok for me .but my problem is  /#/builders/1?budget=5&bedrooms=1&status=9 . by using location.search(key,value) pair i added but its overriding with remaining ones

Comment: it's not though... you are telling every button that they are the only `.search()` clause, because you are using that path rather than your current path.  it may be the correct URL, but it is not correct to put this in every single function.

Comment: no based on my current path i want to add remainig key value pairs . my current path is "/builders/"+r.id

Comment: you still seem to misunderstand.  as far as each button is concerned, their path is the combination of the current URL and any other `.search()` terms that have been added so far.  This must be saved somewhere, and used to add on.  Right now, you are building a new path from scratch every time, because you aren't saving the path anywhere first.

Comment: thanq @ Claies ok .i got it but how to save the first path and how to add new path any clues please

Answer (score 1):

$location return search part of **current** URL.

You can do something like this:

```
$scope.range = function (range) {
    var current = $location.search();
    current.budget = range;
    $location.search(current);
}
```